# detect if a user is navigating from current page in code-behind!

Tags: asp.net

how do i detect if a user if navigating from current page, if yes perform a function. I want everything to be done in code-behind!

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do during that event?

Comment: if the user is navigating from current page thn it will update a record in database!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the solution in which i will call the server side function from client side javascript OnBeforeUnload event using ASP.NET AJAX PageMethods.

For further details on using the PageMethods, refer to this:
[How to call Server Side function from Client Side Code using PageMethods in ASP.NET AJAX « ASP.Net Developer](http://sappidireddy.wordpress.com/2008/03/31/how-to-call-server-side-function-from-client-side-code-using-pagemethods-in-aspnet-ajax/)